# Function : how to pass parameters when inside a switch and a foreach?

Tags: php

It would be so nice if someone is able to show me a brief example of how to pass variables as parameters when inside the function there are a switch and a foreach loop.

What I expect to do is to use all the defined variables in these switch instances ($tax-plates-formes, $tax-editeurs...) in my function as parameters (like this => my_function($tax-plates-formes) or my_function($tax-editeurs)). In order to simply echo the value of the different variables.

Let summarize a similar case:

```
function get_tax_terms_for_the_product() {
 // Get post by post ID.
 if ( ! $post = get_post() ) {
     return '';
 }

 // Get post type by post.
 $post_type = $post->post_type;

 // Get the singular_name of the cpt
 $post_type_obj = get_post_type_object( $post_type );

 // Get post type taxonomies.
 $taxonomies = get_object_taxonomies( $post_type, 'objects' );

 $out = array();
 $out[] .= '<ul class=cpt-ul><li class="bloc-info-elements info-cpt">'.$post_type_obj->labels->singular_name.'</li></ul>';

 foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy_slug => $taxonomy ){

     // Get the terms related to post.
     $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $taxonomy_slug );

     // If tax is hierarchical
     if( is_taxonomy_hierarchical( $taxonomy_slug )) {

         if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

             switch ($taxonomy_slug) {

                 case "tax-plates-formes":
                     $info_plates_formes[] .= '<ul class="ul-info-platesformes">';
                 break;

                 default:
                     $info_categories[] .= '<ul class="ul-info-categories">';
             }

             foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                 if( $term->parent == 0  ) {
                   continue;
                 }

                 // We switch the HTML output in order to give them custom CSS classes
                 switch ($taxonomy_slug) {

                     case "tax-plates-formes":
                         $info_plates_formes[] .= '<li class="info-plateformes">'.$term->name.'</li>';
                     break;

                     default:
                         $info_categories[] .= '<li class="li-info-categories">'.$term->name.'</li>';
                 }
             }
         }
     }

     // If tax isn't hierarchical
     else {

         if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {

             switch ($taxonomy_slug) {

                 case "tax-annees-de-sortie":
                     $info_annee_sortie[] .= '<ul class="ul-info-annee-sorties">';
                 break;

                 case "tax-editeurs":
                     $info_editeurs[] .= '<ul class="ul-info-editeurs">';
                 break;

                 case "tax-modele-economique":
                     $info_modele_economique[] .= '<ul class="ul-info-modele-economique">';
                 break;

             }

             foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

                 // We switch the HTML output in order to give them custom CSS classes
                 switch ($taxonomy_slug) {

                     case "tax-annees-de-sortie":
                         $info_annee_sortie[] .= '<li class="info-annees-de-sortie">'.$term->name.'</li>';
                     break;

                     case "tax-editeurs":
                         $info_editeurs[] .= '<li class="info-editeurs">'.$term->name.'</li>';
                     break;

                     case "tax-modele-economique":
                         $info_modele_economique[] .= '<li class="info-modele-economique">'.$term->name.'</li>';
                     break;
                 }
             }
         }
     }
 } return;
}
```

Can someone helps a bit in order for me to understand?

Regards.

Comment: TThe `foreach` and `switch` statements are already using `$terms` and `$taxonomy_slug`, how do you want to use the parameters instead?

Comment: Are you asking how you can make `$info_plates_formes[] = ...` update the array that you pass as a function argument?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of a proper vocabulary, but I'm not an expert in PHP atm. Basically, I want to use this function by calling it with the variables I have declared, like this : my_function($tax-plates-formes) or my_function($tax--editeurs). I expect that this function will display the string(value) of the variable. All these variables are only string which allow me to put the proper HTML in my pages.

Comment: You can't have `-` in variable names, I guess you mean `$tax_plates_formes`. Where should it display the value of these variables?

Comment: `<li-info-plateformes>` is not correct HTML, I guess you mean `<li class="li-info-plateformes">`

Comment: You have mistakes like that in several places.

Comment: There's nothing special about `switch` and `foreach` statements, you use variables the same way as any other place.

Comment: I have edited my code in order to correct the HTML mistakes and variable mistakes. But the problem remain the same : how to pass these variables which are defined in the function as parameters? All these variables are only strings, and I expect to use get_tax_terms_for_the_product($info_plates_formes) in order to echo the value of $info_plates_formes... and so on for all the others variables.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Change the function to `function get_tax_terms_for_the_product($variable) {` and then use `echo $variable;` wherever you need it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Barmar, but the problem seems to be related with variable which needed to be set as GLOBALS.

I figured it out myself, and instead of using GLOBALS, I decided to not make a function, but include a php file instead in my single.php. This allows me to don't make useless calls to the DB (I needed this function to be used minimum 6 times). With this file, I have just to echo the $variable, and it requires only 1 DB call for the whole process. Thank you.

Comment: Whatever works for you, but your description sounds convoluted. The proper solution to globals is passing parameters. And instead of making a DB call inside this function, make the DB call once outside, and pass the result as a parameter to this function as well.

Comment: Including PHP files should generally not be used as a replacement for calling functions. Use it to load function and class definitions and configuration variables.